# Clustering similar sequences using hidden markov model

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, markov-hidden-model

I have several sequences of different lengths. For example,

```
Seq1 -- "A", "B", "A", "A", "K", "L", "C", "B","C", "D"
Seq2 -- "A", "C", "A", "D", "C", "A", "K", "D"
Seq3 -- "B", "C", "A", "A", "B", "K", "A", "D", "L", "A", "B","C","D"
.................................
......................................
Seq40 - "C","D", "A", "A", "D", "B", "K", "K", "C","D"
```

I want to cluster these sequences using HMM. My idea is to cluster them based on their hidden states. Is there any standard method for clustering sequences using HMM? Also, I know in python, hmmlearn and in R, seqHMM package are good. How can I fit these sequences to cluster them?